# Oracle SQLDeveloper: How to use the 'Filter' toolbar item to query by date?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Having trouble finding documentation on the SqlDeveloper UI's "Filter" item, and what to input to filter by date.  Version 4.1.5.21.  I have tried entering the schema and table prefixes, but the result was the same.  I also tried entering the full name of the month, but the result was the same (and putting the date in quotes, using the to_date() function, omitting the semicolon -- all were unsuccessful).

[image: Date_Question]

Comment: You can use a standard SQL date, e.g. `my_column = DATE'2017-06-17'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official documentation which covers this can be found in section 1.6 of the Oracle SQL Developer 4.1 User Guide located at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#RPTUG10500.

In summary the filter box acts as a WHERE clause on the data in the table, valid predicates can be entered, the text 'WHERE' and suffixed semi-colon are not required.

If the column you are querying (MY_COLUMN) has a data type of DATE then each value will also contain a time which must be taken into consideration. Using an equals operator will only return records with a time of 00:00:00 for the given date.

For example to return all records for the date 17-JUN-2017:

```
MY_COLUMN >= TO_DATE('2017-06-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND MY_COLUMN < TO_DATE('2017-06-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Tested and confirmed working on columns with data types DATE and TIMESTAMP in Oracle SQL Developer v4.1.5.21.